# How to show labels on the left side of the vertical line in a parallel coordinates plot created with echarts4r?

Tags: r, parallel-coordinates, echarts4r

## The context

I know the following code produces the following plot

```
library('echarts4r')

dat  <- structure(list(
  labels = c("string4",
             "string3",
             "string2",
             "string1"),
  quantity = c(19L,
               10L,
               15L,
               20L)),
  row.names = 4:1,
  class = "data.frame")

dat <- dat[order(dat$labels, decreasing = TRUE),]

dat |>
  e_charts(y  = labels, reorder = FALSE) |>
  e_parallel(labels, quantity, opts = list(smooth = TRUE))
```

[image]

## The question

I want these labels (the ones pointed by the blue arrows) to be shown on the left instead of on the right of the vertical line. How can I move them to the left side?

[image]

## What I've tried

I've taken a look at the documentation, as suggested by @socialscientist in its answer, and I've tried the following to no avail.

The following doesn't throw an error, but doesn't move the labels.

```
df <- data.frame(
  labels = c("string4", "string3", "string2", "string1"),
  column2 = c(19L, 10L, 15L, 20L))
df |>
  e_charts(y = labels) |>
  e_labels(position = 'left') |>
  e_parallel(labels, column2)
```

The following throws an error.

```
df <- data.frame(
  labels = c("string4", "string3", "string2", "string1"),
  column2 = c(19L, 10L, 15L, 20L))
df |>
  e_charts(y = labels) |>
  e_parallel(labels, column2) |>
  e_labels(position = 'left')
```

The folowing doesn't throw an error, but doesn't move the labels.

```
df <- data.frame(
  labels = c("string4", "string3", "string2", "string1"),
  column2 = c(19L, 10L, 15L, 20L))
df |>
  e_charts(y = labels) |>
  e_labels(offset = c(123, 123)) |>
  e_parallel(labels, column2)
```

The following doesn't throw an error, but doesn't move the labels.

```
df <- data.frame(
  labels = c("string4", "string3", "string2", "string1"),
  column2 = c(19L, 10L, 15L, 20L))
df |>
  e_charts(y = labels) |>
  e_labels(position = 'insideRight', distance = 123) |>
  e_parallel(labels, column2)
```

Comment: Currently looks like this is not implemented in `echarts4r`. My suggestions are that you either (a) pass your chart to  `echarts4rOutput()` and try to manually figure out how to change the way `parallelAxis` works since the Y axis you see is NOT the actual chart's Y-axis, (b) swap to `MASS` or `ggplot2` to create your parallel coordinates plot https://r-graph-gallery.com/93-parrallel-plot (which can be made interactive with e.g. shiny or whatever), or (c) write up your own solution with D3.js https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an effectively method to feed the necessary input into `e_parallel`. However, You can change it as an after thought.

I used this function to flip the defaults for `axisTick.length` and `axisLabel.margin` and `axisLabel.align` for the `parallelAxis` (left side only).

```
fixLabs <- function(plt) {
  plt$x$opts$parallelAxis[[1]]$axisTick <- list(length = -5) # default is +5
  plt$x$opts$parallelAxis[[1]]$axisLabel <- list(margin = -8, # default is +8
                                                 align = "right")
  plt
}
```

This is how you use it.

```
dat |>
  e_charts(y  = labels, reorder = FALSE) |>
  e_parallel(labels, quantity, 
             opts = list(smooth = TRUE))  %>% 
  fixLabs()
```

[image]